# How to use more than one query in Pentaho Report Designer?

Tags: sql, database, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I am trying to add two queries in Pentaho Report Designer so that I could get query results from more than one table.

Here is my case:

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT
     `raw_crawl_shop_list`.`sales`,
     `raw_crawl_shop_list`.`keyword`,
     `raw_crawl_shop_list`.`number`
FROM
     `raw_crawl_shop_list`
LIMIT 1
```

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT
     `dim_keyword_tag`.`keyword`,
     `dim_keyword_tag`.`tag`
FROM
     `dim_keyword_tag`
```

**My problem:**

I want to use the five columns selected from two table respectively (that means there's no relationship between these columns, I just use them seperately), However, in Pentaho Report Designer. I could only use columns selected from one single query.

As the picture shown below:

[image][image]

If I choose Query 1, columns selected by Column 2 disappear, if I choose Query 2 the same with Query 1.

**My question:**

How could I use two queries in Pentaho Report Designer in a single report **OR** is there a way to combine these two sql queries in a single one with the three columns from the first and the two columns from the second?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two possible way of reading two queries in PRD.

1. Creating a **SUB-REPORT** and then define the second query. Check this [wiki](http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Freport_designer_user_guide%2Ftask_sub_reports.html) for more.
2. **JOINING** the two tables inside a single query, as correctly said by Kotukunui.

Comment: I don't quite understand the SUB-REPORT, i think i'll learn it deeper tomorrow. For JOIN method, since the two tables share no common attribute as i mentioned ("keyword" is not actually the same key), i think i can't join them this way.

Comment: @SummerSun sub-reports are like reports inside a report. In the main report u can insert a subreport and u can use the second query in the subreport.. This will generate u a single report but with data coming in from two differnt sources. You can read in the wiki i attached above.

Comment: @Rishu Nice Answer. But there is another way of doing it I answered this question with that method.

Comment: @SummerSun Check my answer for another method.

Comment: @Rishu what about if I am reading queries from multiable database and shames. what are the possible ways to do such thing

Answer (score 0):

If both tables are in the same database, just JOIN them into a single query

```
SELECT
     `raw_crawl_shop_list`.`sales`,
     `raw_crawl_shop_list`.`keyword`,
     `raw_crawl_shop_list`.`number`,
     `dim_keyword_tag`.`tag`
FROM
     `raw_crawl_shop_list` JOIN `dim_keyword_tag` ON `raw_crawl_shop_list`.`keyword` = `dim_keyword_tag`.`keyword`
```

Comment: thanks but there's no relationship between the two `keyword`, so the JOIN ...ON... will not work for this case. I actually want both keywords.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way of getting values from multiple queries.

Add a label, and edit the "value" attribute-expression. Set either of the following formula depending on your requirement. In "value" attribute-value type your query name.

This way you can directly refer to your query written in JDBC connection.

```
=MULTIVALUEQUERY("yourqueryname")
=SINGLEVALUEQUERY("yourqueryname")
```

Else you can write your query inside the expression which takes the following input parameters,

```
SINGLEVALUEQUERY()
SINGLEVALUEQUERY([query:string]; [column:string])
SINGLEVALUEQUERY([query:string]; [column:string]; [querytimeout:integer])

MULTIVALUEQUERY([query:string])
MULTIVALUEQUERY([query:string]; [column:string])
MULTIVALUEQUERY([query:string]; [column:string]; [querytimeout:integer])
MULTIVALUEQUERY([query:string]; [column:string]; [querytimeout:integer][limit:integer] )
```

[This](https://www.on-reporting.com/blog/using-queries-in-formulas-in-pentaho/) will give you a better understanding of it.